# looping over variables in pandas and for each month, computing OHLC and storing data into new dataframe's columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a financial close price (weekly) data which looks like this:

```
Date        V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7
2010-01-01  77.31   66.94   52.33   34.94   81.38   84.75   482
2010-01-08  78.05   68.85   52.84   34.66   90.15   95.61   508
2010-01-15  79.29   68.3    53.61   35.33   86.97   97.87   490
2010-01-22  80.57   68.19   55.43   35.8    86.04   99.26   480
2010-01-29  81.87   68.79   55.84   35.6    83.36   98.53   462
2010-02-05  83.7    70.35   57.3    36.57   84.54   91.83   464
2010-02-12  81.85   68.32   56.4    37.35   81.2    90.75   455
2010-02-19  82.66   69.04   56.21   36.89   81.85   93.98   457
2010-02-26  86.32   69.7    57.43   37.12   83.96   96.43   467
2010-03-05  85.37   69.98   57.34   36.71   84.01   94.83   466
2010-03-12  84.04   69.76   56.74   36.98   83.02   93.92   466
2010-03-19  84.37   69.76   56.77   37.07   83.29   95.04   458
2010-03-26  85.7    70.06   56.62   36.81   81.64   94.84   459
2010-04-02  85.38   70.72   56.03   36.78   83.91   94.98   464
2010-04-09  89.21   71.7    58.38   37.49   86.95   98.74   471
2010-04-16  89.74   72.35   58.74   38.05   85.58   98.28   487
2010-04-23  90.72   74.26   60.61   38.64   90.5    100.18  492
2010-04-30  99.79   78.67   65.14   38.89   95.82   108.87  494
2010-05-07  102.34  81.48   63.45   41.87   93.18   106.2   478
2010-05-14  96.42   79.81   62.57   41.23   88.94   102.23  484
2010-05-21  96.17   76.9    61.06   39.28   88.22   97.8    444
2010-05-28  95.73   77.67   61.1    39.88   92.88   96.84   421
```

Here V1, V2... V7 are some companies for which weekly closing prices are given in the above table data.

What I want to do is to calculate:

1. for each month, what is open, close, high and low prices
2. open should be the price on the first date in Date column for that month, and close should be the last date, obviously, right?

I am using the below code which returns me the result as shown below the code:

```
def calculate(x):
    open = x.loc[x.index.min(), "V1"]
    high = x.loc[x.index, "V1"].max()
    low = x.loc[x.index, "V1"].min()
    close = x.loc[x.index.max(), "V1"]
    return open, high, low, close

result = pd.DataFrame()
result = df.groupby(df["Date"].dt.to_period("M")).apply(calculate)

result
```

Result of the above:

```
Date
2010-01    (77.31, 81.87, 77.31, 81.87)  
2010-02    (83.7, 86.32, 81.85, 86.32)   
2010-03    (85.37, 85.7, 84.04, 85.7)    
2010-04    (85.38, 99.79, 85.38, 99.79)  
2010-05    (102.34, 102.34, 95.73, 95.73)
                        ...
```

Now I wanted to take these tuples into respective columns, along with the Date:

1. Date, Open, High, Low, Close

And also,
2. I want to repeat above function for all the variables (V1 through V7) using single loop operation or something.

Could someone please suggest me how I should be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can also try:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq = '1M')).agg(**{'open': ('V1','first'), 'high' : ('V1', 'max'), 'low' : ('V1', 'min'), 'close': ('V1','last')}))
```

OUTPUT:

```
              open    high    low  close
Date                                    
2010-01-31   77.31   81.87  77.31  81.87
2010-02-28   83.70   86.32  81.85  86.32
2010-03-31   85.37   85.70  84.04  85.70
2010-04-30   85.38   99.79  85.38  99.79
2010-05-31  102.34  102.34  95.73  95.73
```

NOTE: you can also use `resample`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').resample('1M').agg({'V1': ['min', 'max', 'first', 'last']})
```

Updated Answer:
`

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date').resample('1M').agg(['min', 'max', 'first', 'last'])
df1.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0),df1.columns.get_level_values(1).map({'min': 'low', 'max': 'high', 'first': 'open', 'last': 'close'}))]
```

Comment: resampe returned only min, max, first and last column names.. i can rename these, no issues, but ant idea, if I want to run through all Vs, e.g. V1, V2, V3, can i apply for loop here?

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque check updated answer. Also, there are couple of ways to rename the columns I've added 1 way.

Comment: thank :) it solved a lot things... also i learnt something new...